# IF conditional inside a nested Has_one

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, nested, nested-attributes, conditional-statements

psuedo relational run down
Clients -> has_many -> Departments -> has_many -> Tasks -> has_one -> Hazard

On the Tasks#show I currently the hazard only if it exists (as determined by a Yes/no question in the Task form). If it exists I would like to show the Hazard with a conditional statement that shows the "fill out form" link and "Incomplete" text if the Hazard form has not been completed. and a "view form" and "complete text if the Hazard form has been completed.

here is an excerpt of code from the app/views/tasks/show.html.erb

```
    <% if @task.Hazard_exist  == 'Yes' %>   
<tr>    
<td>Hazard</td>     
<% if @task.Hazard.nil? %>      
    <td><%= link_to 'Fill Out Form', new_client_department_task_Access_path(@client,@department,@task) %></td>
    <td id="incomplete">Incomplete!</td>
    <td class="risk_val">Form not complete</td> 
<% else %>      
    <td><%= link_to 'View Form', client_department_task_Hazard_path(@client,@department,@task) %>   
            <%= link_to 'Edit Form', edit_client_department_task_Hazard_path(@client,@department,@task) %></td>
            <td id="complete">Complete</td> 
            <td class="risk_val"><%= @task.Hazard.risk_total%></td>
<% end %>   
</tr>
    <% end %>
```

This works but the issue is that even if I "fill out the form" and then hit cancel the row of the database @task.Hazard is no longer nil. Thus identifying the Hazard form as "Complete". Ideally I'd like to make it so that the Hazard is validated by presence of certain fields but the client wants it to be able to be submitted as "in progress" So My plan is that the form will be able to be submitted with no validations. However, the conditional statement in the Tasks#show would be dependent on a key value in the Hazard model not being blank.

i.e. replacing this line

```
<% if @task.Hazard.nil? %>
```

with

```
<% if @task.Hazard.risk_total == '' %>
```

However, I get the "undefined" method issue when trying to do this.

Is there any easy work around here in order to use this conditional requirement? Or is simply putting a validation on the form the best way?

Comment: You mean `@task.hazard` and `@task.access`, right?

Comment: No what I meant is, you're calling `hazard` not `Hazard`, right? `Hazard` is the class... I have no idea what you'd get when you call that, but surely you want the instance of hazard that belongs to task, ie. `task.hazard`

Comment: Ah yes. I understand. Good call. Unfortunately my problem is that the value of my calculated risk_total defaults to 0. I am unsure whether my method will work.

Answer (score 0):

If the client wants this to be able to be submitted in progress then you're not going to get where you want to go just checking for existence. Instead, add a `complete:boolean` attribute on your models that need to be submitted in progress, then either allow these to be set by the user or in a callback.

For instance, a good way to do this might be to provide two buttons at the bottom of the form:

```
= submit_tag "Save as Draft"
= button_tag "Save as Complete", :type => "button", :id => "complete"
```

You can then call a script that takes the click event on `button#complete`, adds a hidden field `complete = true`, and submits the form.

That script might look like:

```
$('button#complete').click( function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('form#my_form').append('<input type="hidden" name="hazard[complete]" value="true">').submit();
});
```

Or, you could put a callback in the model that checks for whether all the fields on the hazard have been filled out to, and then marks it as complete.

Then in your conditional you just would write:

```
if @task.hazard.complete
```

Comment: Just to clarify. I would add a hidden field to the form. Then I would use a Jquery or javascript call to check it as complete when the complete button is pushed?